# xampp in window 7 cannot access files in subfolder inside C:/xampp/htdocs

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

In `httpd.conf` I've changed port to : `Listen 8080` and `ServerName localhost:8080`

Now on my browser I had to enter `http://localhost:8080` and everything seems to work fine and I can see all my files and folders inside `htdocs` directory.

The problem is that I cannot go inside any folders under `htdocs` for example: `C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress`

When I click on `wordpress/` in the browser it says

> Webpage is not available

And something weird is if I type `http://localhost:8080/wordpress` the URL would automatically change to `http://localhost/wordpress/`.
And I get same error : "`Webpage is not available`"

Is this because I change the port to 8080 ?
Am I missing some other config ?

Comment: @ApulGupta If skype was running on port 80 and 443, he couldn't even start apache. Also you can set skype to use a different port.

Comment: hi no i don't have skype installed and i am able to start apache without problem, its just that i have to type in localhost:8080 instead of just localhost

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to restart apache whenever you make any change in conf file

you seems to be not using fresh wordpress. And browser url removing the 8080 because of some htaccess rule.

you can test apache by making a folder with name test in htdocs. And put a simple php file with this code

```
<?php 
    phpinfo();
```

and save it as testapache.php

and browse it by

http://localhost:8080/test/testapache.php